# Ionic and Appium

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, appium, ionic3, e2e-testing

I am trying to set up E2E-Tests with Appium on a Ionic3 Application.
For me it’s not clear when the Webdriver has access to “id” or “accessibility id”. Often I have only xpath as option which is not usable because of the platform specific path. I would like to have one test script which works on iOS and Android (which would work with the “accessibility ids”.

I set up a dummy-app for testing this behavior: https://github.com/olivierschmid/appium_testapp

The Home page contains a button

```
 <button id="myButtonID" name="myButtonName" ion-button block (click)="gotoAbout()">Click me</button>
```

On iOS the inspector of Appium only shows xpath option. On Android there is also the “id”. 
On another Ionic Apps it's just the other way (Accessibility IDs on iOS, no IDs on Android...).

[image: screenshot ios]
[image: screenshot android]

Any ideas how I can tell Ionic to generate the IDs?
Thanks Oli

Here are the capabilities I used in Appium:

```
iOS
{
“platformName”: “iOS”,
“app”: “/Users/u105791/AppDev/testapp/platforms/ios/build/device/MyApp.ipa”,
“udid”: “12345 - uid of iPhone”,
“deviceName”: “441fabb1600ab393e963fcba2adfae975e8282d5”,
“automationName”: “XCUITest”
}

Android
{
“platformName”: “Android”,
“app”: “/AppDev/testapp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk”,
“udid”: “12345 - uid of Samsung galaxy”,
“deviceName”: “Android”,
“automationName”: “uiautomator2”
}
```

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution @Olivier Schmid?

Comment: @AndréHerculano - It's working now. We set class-ids on all elements we want interact to. this is working so far (ionic 3 und ionic 4).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to have it like:

- iOS => AccessibilityId
- Android => content-desc

it works this way for Appium automation testing of **ReactNative** application, might work for **Ionic** as well.

Just make it work as AccessibilityId in iOS and then check if you have same value on Android under `content-desc` element property

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the native projects (Xcode, Android) is generated by Ionic and I did not found out to influence if / how AccessibilityId and content-desc is set.

Comment: I know this question is old. But did you fix it? @OlivierSchmid

Comment: I don't use it anymore @Mike_NotGuilty